# Publishing .NET Core web api/angular application to IIS

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core

I am having issues deploying my .NET Core 2.0 project to IIS

I followed the instructions listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#common-errors

I publish using Visual  Studios
[image]

When I try to access my published project via the browser I get this error 
message

[image]

Looking at the Event Viewer on my IIS server I see the following error

[image]

I installed the .NET SDK so the dotnet command is available at the terminal.

I added a global.json file that specifies the correct dotnet SDK per the instructions found in this link: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/495 but that did not resolve the issue.

How can I publish my .NET Core 2.0 WebAPI+Angular4 project to IIS?

EDIT:

I can launch the application manually with `dotnet MPMWebsiteLogins.dll`

EDIT 2:

I updated my web.config and explicitly specified my path for dotnet.exe and MPMWebsiteLogins.dll

`<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments="C:\inetpub\WebApps\HPIssuesUtilityV2\MPMWebsiteLogins.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`

I am now getting this error in my event viewer:

`Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MPMWEBSITELOGINS' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\WebApps\HPIssuesUtilityV2\' created process with commandline 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe C:\inetpub\WebApps\HPIssuesUtilityV2\MPMWebsiteLogins.dll' but failed to listen on the given port '1989'`

[image]

Comment: What's the output if you just run `dotnet MPMWebsiteLogins.dll`?

Comment: @Kirk the application runs just fine with `dotnet MPMWebsiteLogins.dll`

Comment: For the original problem - you need add the path to where `dotnet.exe` is to your System PATH environment variable and you *have to* restart your server. For the port problem - likely something (maybe even your own application) is using this port. Make sure that you are not running anything that uses this port. If this is a dev machine stop IISExpress (from the tray/notification area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to execute `net stop was /y` followed by `net start w3svc` from the command prompt to pick up a change to the system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing the [ACNM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x) module for reverse proxy. If you install the [.Net core windows server hosting bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore.2.0.0-windowshosting) it should install all the require components for you. You can double check by checking your IIS modules, it should have ASPnetcore.